# Cannot run 'sudo npm i' on AWS server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, github, npm, glibc

I am working with Github and AWS to get my website up and have encountered a road block. After cloning my repository to the AWS server I am using to host my website, I tried running 'sudo npm i' in that directory but got an error stating that there is no package.json. So, I went back to Github, created a package.json and cloned the updated repository to a second AWS instance. Now when trying to run 'sudo npm i', I get the error:

node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)

I have tried using the solutions to the other stackoverflow forum for `GLIBC_2.28' not found but none have worked. Weirdly enough, when I run 'npm -v' the console shows that I have npm installed. I am trying to run a build with npm and am not sure what to do/where I went wrong.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Commands I am trying to run: 'sudo npm i', 'sudo npm run build'

Error messages I have gotten (not word for word):
(1) no package.json (2) [the current error message I am getting] `GLIBC_2.28' not found (3) [one I got earlier] sudo: node: command not found (4) [one I got earlier] E: You have broken packages

I tried other stackoverflow forums pertaining the same error messages I am receiving and other website that also related to the error messages I am receiving. I am simply copying and pasting the 'solution code' and none have worked so far.

Comment: Which linux are you using? And what is your node version?

Comment: Linux 4.15.0-1021-aws x86_64, node: v14.21.2

Comment: normaly this error comes with node18 and older debian versions, like ubuntu 18. If you reinstall nodejs you should get an advice what to do for installing the missing library. Look carefully to the output and follow the instructions.

Comment: Ok thank you. One quick thing: when I update nodejs I get - 'nodejs is already the newest version (18.13.0-deb-1nodesource1).' But when I run 'node -v' I get 'v14.21.2'. Do you know what I should do from here?

Comment: What is the output from `which node`? It sounds like you have a _different_ (old) version of `node` somewhere on your `PATH`.

Comment: /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.2/bin/node

Comment: You have nvm installed. This is node version manager, which allows you to easly switch between node versions. Did you also manually install nodejs by apt install nodejs?

Comment: The think is you said you update nodejs. With nvm installed you should not use direct installation- Do a " nvm list" and post it in your answer please. [Here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) how nvm works. I would reinstall  the aws install and start from the scratch, if this is possible for you